# A Local Service gets 401 error accessing ASP website

Tags: iis-7, windows-authentication, asp-classic

I have Anonymous access disabled for Active Directory Auth via Windows Authentication and the service I use to run an ASP page every 15 minutes gets a 401 unauthorized when it tries to run. How do I allow the service which runs locally to the web server access the site without enabling windows authentication?

Environment: Windows Server 2008 64 bit, IIS 7, Running classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. In 2008 you can control the authentication methods per subfolder in addition to per site and per server.